# Convert string to javascript array in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have `ViewBag.Result` with string value `"[['Garreth','VP'],['Johan','IT'],['Test','QA']]"`

I want to convert it as javascript array

```
var dataset =
[
    ['Garreth','VP'],
    ['Johan','IT'],
    ['Test','QA']
]
```

Obviously `var dataset = '@ViewBag.Result'` doesn't work because javascript treat is as string but not array. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the single quotes:

`var dataset = @ViewBag.Result`

Comment: i feel stupid but that works for me, thanks!